# How to use XMLHttpRequest and Fetch Polyfill for uploading images using chrome extension and firebase

Tags: firebase, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I'm developing a chrome extension that takes screenshot when a blacklisted URL from my array list has been visited.
So far I'm able to do

1. Get the Screenshot and its corresponding URL
2. Write event Logs in my firestore database
3. Read User data and black list array

however, I'm encountering a Reference error when I'm uploading the images thru my firestore database. Further researching drops me into using xmlhttprequest and fetch polyfill in my workspace so that I can able to the uploads. However I'm a newb to those since I'm more familiar on firebase SDK and firestore.

Here's my code

```
///<reference types="chrome"/>
//Imports
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
import { ref, getDownloadURL, uploadBytes } from 'firebase/storage';


firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
var afs = firebase.firestore();
var event = afs.collection('profileLogs');
var session = afs.collection('sessions');


 chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true }, (tab) => {
   let url = tab[0].url;
   let title = tab[0].title; 
   getBlackList();
    eventTimeStamp = new Date();
     event.add({
      // Log Data Field Goes Here
     isIncognito: tab.incognito,
     });

   for (let i = 0; i < blackList.length; i++) {
        if (url == blackList[i].samplesite) {
          // Takes Screenshot
          setTimeout(() => {
            getScreenshot();
          }, 100);

   // Add Session Event
          sessionTimeStamp = new Date();
          session.add({
            */ Session Log Data Field goes here
          });

          //SMS API
        }
      }

}

// Takes Screenshots
function getScreenshot() {
  chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab((data) => {
    ssUrl = data;
    console.log('screenshot', ssUrl);
    ssPathName = 'sessionSS' + Math.random();
    const storage = getStorage();
    imageRef = ref(storage, ssPathName);
    imageBaseRef = uploadBytes(imageRef, ssUrl);
  });
}

// Get Blacklist sites
async function getBlackList() {
  const list = await afs
    .collection('blacklistSites')
    .where('username', '==', creds)
    .get();
  blackList = list.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
}
```

When the screenshot is now being uploaded to my firestorage, I get this error
[image]

I've been searching for days now but there's no starter tutorial or like a basic guide on how to use either of the approaches.

Comment: You'll have to write a polyfill yourself or find an existing one. It may be easier to just open a new window using chrome.windows.create with a html page from your extension where you will be able to use XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Do you have any starting reference tutorial specifically for firebase? I really don't know how to create one or use one at the moment due to my limited knowledge and currently my resources for this are limited.

Comment: It seems Manifest V3 still doesn't support xmlhttp request api so I couldn't do the usual firebase upload